# Mime types for custom file type in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, mime-types

I am trying to upload a custom file type with our own file extension through Jmeter file upload. My custom filetype, with a custom extension, is actually a zip archive containing various xml and other files.

I am not sure about the mime type  that i should use for custom file. However i tried with application/zip and application/sfp(extension of my file). Getting a Response code: 415 in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Record the action using [jmeter recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html). It will create the upload request for you and will set the MIME type. Use that MIME type to check if it works.